# "Disk read error occurred" booting from hard drive or USB on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, boot, raid, windows-server-2008

Here's the setup: an Athlon X2, 4 GB of RAM, and a 2x2 RAID 10 array of 4 500GB drives, which also houses the OS.

After a usual reboot the machine didn't respond to ping. I connected it to a display and saw a boot options selection screen: restore Windows or boot normally, that kind of thing. I chose Boot Normally and it rebooted immediately, showing the same screen to me again. I chose Restore Windows. This time it showed the "Windows is loading files" bar.

As it filled up completely some graphical artifacts appeared near the top of the screen (just three red pixels near the top) with a message "Disk read error occurred. Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to reboot." The RAID seemed to have initialized correctly, so I got a copy of Windows Server and did the usual `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixboot`, made sure that the 100 MB partition was active, but none of that helped.

I tried booting from a USB drive, but that results in "Disk error occurred." Perhaps the motherboard is at fault?

The drives have some sensitive, critical data, so a full recovery is imperative.

Comment: Can you move the drives into a different computer to recover the data?

Comment: I can and that's probably what I'm going to do now that the usb stick boot is out of the picture.